# regex to verify string is formatted the right way

Tags: java, regex

I have text coming from a third party API an SMS to be precise. I need to verify that it is formatted as follows `ren#firstname#lastname` with regex.

The first `#` should appear in the fourth character, the second `#` can be anywhere after that but not in the last or second last position of the string And the two `#` should not follow each other.

> Is this possible with regex and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Assuming the `"#"` must appear exactly twice in the string, try `^[^#]{3}#[^#]+#[^#]{2,}$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/z3YDck/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt backed up with some unit tests. No doubt others will come up with a superior regex, plug them into the test and try them out.

**Edit**

My original regex does the job but I think that `^[^#]{3}#[^#]+#[^#]{2,}$` from @CarySwoveland in the comments is the regex of choice so I've replaced mine with his.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class SOExample {

    public boolean match(String s) {
        String pattern = "^[^#]{3}#[^#]+#[^#]{2,}$";
        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(s);
        return m.matches();
    }

    @Test
    public void match_returns_true_for_example_string() {
        assertTrue(match("ren#firstname#lastname"));
    }

    @Test
    public void match_returns_false_when_the_first_hash_is_not_the_forth_character() {
        assertFalse(match("renX#firstname#lastname"));
    }

    @Test
    public void match_returns_false_when_the_second_hash_is_in_the_last_position_of_the_string() {
        assertFalse(match("ren#firstname#"));
    }

    @Test
    public void match_returns_false_when_the_second_hash_is_in_the_second_last_position_of_the_string() {
        assertFalse(match("ren#firstname#l"));
    }

    @Test
    public void match_returns_false_when_the_the_two_hashes_do_not_follow_each_other() {
        assertFalse(match("ren#firstname##lastname"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland edited to include your improvement, tests passing.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the regex would be `^.{3}#.*#.*$`

If you want to get the actual values of the three fields, use capture groups:

```
  ^(.{3})#(.*)#(.*)$
```

Comment: This fails the following unit tests in my answer: `match_returns_false_when_the_second_hash_is_in_the_last_position_of_the_string`, `match_returns_false_when_the_second_hash_is_in_the_second_last_position_of_the_string`, `match_returns_false_when_the_the_two_hashes_do_not_follow_each_other`

Answer (score -1):

```
ren#[a-zA-Z]+#[a-zA-Z]+
```

Otherwise, if "ren" can be any other 3 letter word, then

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}#[a-zA-Z]+#[a-zA-Z]+
```

If you want to accept numbers as well, then

```
.{3}#.+#.+
```

Comment: This fails the following unit test in my answer: `match_returns_false_when_the_second_hash_is_in_the_second_last_position_of_the_string`